# single quotes in SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

Im writing a php script that is used to update a database but it is giving errors when i tries to run the query it returns an error along the lines of

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id=15"' at line 1
```

Where it says "To use near" seems to display part of the query after there is a space in the data. Im assuming i need to put single quotes around where the data to the query from the php variables but when i try to put them in (even escaping the quotes) i get parse errors from the script

The SQL Query is

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE Videos SET Title=".$_POST['Title'].", Preacher=".$_POST['Preacher'].", Date=".$_POST['Date'].", Service=".$_POST['Service'].", File=".$_POST['File'].", Description=".$_POST['Description']."WHERE id=".$_GET['vid_id']."\"") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thank in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the variables properly and surround them by single quotes:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE
                Videos
            SET
                Title = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Title'])."',
                Preacher = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Preacher'])."', 
                Date = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Date'])."',
                Service = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Service'])."',
                File = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['File'])."',
                Description = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Description'])."'
            WHERE
                id = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['vid_id'])."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Without escaping your variables properly, you are making yourself vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

**EDIT**

To simplify the above, you can do a few tricks:

```
// Apply mysql_escape_string to every item in $_POST
array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
// Get rid of $_POST, $_POST['Title'] becomes $p_Title
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'p_');

// Use sprintf to build your query
$query = sprintf("UPDATE
                Videos
            SET
                Title = '%s',
                Preacher = '%s', 
                Date = '%s',
                Service = '%s',
                File = '%s',
                Description = '%s'
            WHERE
                id = '%s'",
            $p_Title,
            $p_Preacher,
            $p_Service,
            $p_File,
            $p_Description,
            mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['vid_id']));

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note that mixing $_POST and $_GET variables is not encouraged. You should supply the update ID through an hidden input field in the form.

Comment: wow, accepted  :)  I think proper use of sprintf() will be better, both for readability and performances

Answer (score 4):

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://docs.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) and [sql injections](http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection) have already been mentioned.
But right now your script (painstakingly) has to mix the sql statement with the data/parameters and in the next step the MySQL server has to separate the data from the statement.
Using (server-side) [prepared statements](http://docs.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) both "parts" of your query are sent separately and the sql parser (of your MySQL server) can never get "confused" about where the statement ends and the data begins.

The [php-mysql](http://docs.php.net/mysql) module doesn't know prepared statements but [php-mysql**i**](http://docs.php.net/mysql) and [PDO](http://docs.php.net/pdo) do.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', '...', '...'); 
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('
  UPDATE
    Videos
  SET
    Title=:title ,
    Preacher=:preacher ,
    Date=:date ,
    Service=:service ,
    File=:file ,
    Description=:description
  WHERE
    id=:id
');
$stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
$stmt->bindParam(':preacher', $_POST['preacher']);
$stmt->bindParam(':date', $_POST['date']);
$stmt->bindParam(':service', $_POST['service']);
$stmt->bindParam(':file', $_POST['file']);
$stmt->bindParam(':description', $_POST['description']);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']); // really _GET?
$stmt->execute();
```

May seem a lot of bloat if you use $stmt for only one operation. But consider that otherwise you have to call mysql_real_escape_string() for each parameter.

Comment: right, but you are calling bindParm() for each parameter too :)

Comment: Yes, that's my point - only the other way round ;-) The whole bindParm() thing might seem like overhead but you'd have to call real_escape_string() otherwise (or make sure a numeric parameter really is numeric)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using DB API directly (no DB abstraction level) the best solution is to use DB escape function.

Just use [**`mysql_real_escape_string()`**](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

```
<?php
// Your query
$query = sprintf("UPDATE Videos SET Title='%s', preacher='%s', Date='%s', "
                     ."Service='%s', File='%s', Description='%s' WHERE id='%s'",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Title']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Preacher']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Date']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Service']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['File']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Description']),
                 mysql_real_escape_string(($_GET['vid_id']));
?>
```

As a bonus you'll get a really improved security against [SQL INJECTION attacs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) your previous code was prone.

In the case you would simply escape slashes you have, again, to use php/mysql functions [**`addslashes()`**](http://php.net/addaslashes) will do the job in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you putting a `\"` right at the end, this puts a `"` on to the end of your SQL but you don't have one at the start?

Try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE Videos SET Title=".$_POST['Title'].", Preacher=".$_POST['Preacher'].", Date=".$_POST['Date'].", Service=".$_POST['Service'].", File=".$_POST['File'].", Description=".$_POST['Description']."WHERE id=".$_GET['vid_id']) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

REMOVE \", from:

```
id=".$_GET['vid_id']."\""
```