# Avoid Mysql quotes - also at SELECT query?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="SELECT `name` FROM $table ";
```

what happens if into the records from `name` column there are quotes (') ?
I need to change that SELECT query? And how? I noticed that Mysql reports an error like this:

1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'activation)'' at line 3

'cause 'activation is not good...
but well...why can i read and manipulate the string variable if it returns an error?
I saw exemples that use a WHERE condition...but I don't need that, I have to select all the records from the `name` column... please help

edit:

```
//..connection to database part, then...


    $sql="SELECT `name` FROM $table ";
    $res=mysql_query($sql);


    $c=0;
    function contains($str, array $arr)
    {
        foreach($arr as $a) {
            if (stripos($str,$a) !== false) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    $arr = array("à","â","æ","ç","è","é","ê","ë","î","ï","ô","œ","ù","û","ü","¡","¿","ñ","í","ó","ú","ä","ö","ß","ÿ");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
        $contiene = 0;
        $link=strtolower($row[0]);
        $link = iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $link);
        $link= utf8_decode($link);
        $link = stripslashes($link);
        $link = mysql_real_escape_string($link);
        if (contains($link, $arr)) {
            echo "String containing special char\n";
            echo "$link\n";         
            $link = str_replace("à", "a", $link);
            $link = str_replace("â", "a", $link);
            $link = str_replace("æ", "ae", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ç", "c", $link);
            $link = str_replace("è", "e", $link);
            $link = str_replace("é", "e", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ê", "e", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ë", "e", $link);
            $link = str_replace("î", "i", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ï", "i", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ô", "o", $link);
            $link = str_replace("œ", "oe", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ù", "u", $link);
            $link = str_replace("û", "u", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ü", "ue", $link);
            $link = str_replace("¡", "-", $link);
            $link = str_replace("¿", "-", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ñ", "n", $link);
            $link = str_replace("í", "i", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ó", "o", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ú", "u", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ä", "ae", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ö", "oe", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ß", "ss", $link);
            $link = str_replace("ÿ", "y", $link);
            echo "String with replaced char\n";
            echo "$link\n";
            $c++;
            $contiene = 1;
        }
        $link=ereg_replace("[^a-z0-9\-]", "-", $link);
        echo "String after ereplace:\n";        
        echo "$link\n"; 
        if ($contiene ==1){
            $l="UPDATE $table 
                SET link_rewrite='$link'
                WHERE $table.name = '$row[0]'   "; 
            $r=mysql_query($l);
            if (!$r) {
            echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";
            }
        }

    }

    echo "Update catlink_rewrite( $c )";

?>
```

what's wrong?

**String containing the accent or special char**:

acer aspire one d270-n261g326ck noir + housse néoprène noir & rouge avec pochette frontale lneo-10 - jusqu'à 10,2"

**String after str_replace**:

acer aspire one d270-n261g326ck noir + housse neoprene noir & rouge avec pochette frontale lneo-10 - jusqu'a 10,2"

**String after ereg_replace**:

acer-aspire-one-d270-n261g326ck-noir---housse-neoprene-noir---rouge-avec-pochette-frontale-lneo-10---jusqu-a-10-2-

**Mysql error**:

1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'à 10,2"'' at line 3

Comment: Selecting data from a table should not be a problem. Are you subsequently using it to `INSERT` into another? This sounds suspiciously like a bad [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: What is the `activation`? Is it table name or value in the name column?

Comment: Inserting a variable into a SQL string can be dangeous. Please be sure that there is no evil sql injection inside.

Comment: @tadman are you sure? yes, at the end...I have to UPDATE but before i use stripslashes and mysql_real_escape_string but no success...now edit the question to let you understand...

Comment: @YogendraSingh is a string into the record from the name column...name column is full of long strings

Comment: Good old fashioned escaping: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [single quotes in SQL Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938923/single-quotes-in-sql-query)

Comment: Oh my... most of those string operations make little sense, especially the encoding conversion. Your immediate problem is that SQL-escaping is the ***last*** thing you do before putting the value into the query. Please, read the beforelinked Escapism article, and probably the rest of the articles on that page as well.

Comment: @smepie What is `$ps`? And `var_dump($query);` and paste it here.

Comment: @Claudrian resource(6) of type (mysql result) for SELECT AND  bool(false)
1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'activation)'' at line 3 ...for UPDATE

Comment: i have 572 errors like this, this means that i'm not able to strip the quotes from the strings, please help

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: You really *must* stop using `mysql_query` immediately. There are truckloads of questions on Stack Overflow going over the basics of SQL escaping because people keep having the same problems. If you use PDO or `mysqli` properly this wouldn't be an issue. Learning those interfaces takes only a half hour, and converting existing code isn't especially difficult. Using PDO correctly is also a lot easier than going through the trouble of using the creaky `mysql_query` interface  and checking that every single value you're inserting is escaped. PDO will do that for you when using placeholders.

Comment: yes, ok...but don't understand why guys from stackoverflow deny my questions now... i can't put questions anymore. Only about this? i don't think it's a right way... ok, i learn about PDO but it's not good to ban me...it's like a ban, i didn't do anything of bad. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$row[0] = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
```

Do this before the `UPDATE query` where the `$row[0]` is used. You are not escaping anything. Your code makes my eyes bleed... and is very unsafe.

Comment: name is a column, not a table..the table is $table ;-)

Comment: @smepie Yeah... you lost me first. Fixed the comment :)

Comment: @smepie Changed the answer. Also consider `var_dump()-ing the $row[0]` and pasting here if this does not fix it.

Comment: YEAH! string(20) "VTECH Biblio\'Bébé"
bool(true)... really thank you! but why unsafe?

Comment: @smepie You're welcome! Search and learn about SQL injection. You'll understand. Short story long, values need to be escaped or malicious crafted queries can be used to hack into your site/database/business... whatever. But learn about it. It's important.

Comment: It's not just malicious queries. It's anything with the same delimiters used in your query. When "Jimmy O'Neil" wants to sign up on your site he's in for a rude surprise if you haven't escaped your values.